# Is shutdown, a command or an application?

Tags: windows, restart, shutdown

We can see that while creating a shortcut for shutting down or restart the computer, the command is shutdown.exe /s /t 00 blah blah,
So, my question is that is it an application or just a command in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown is a command line application. You can learn more about it here:
https://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm